# jQuery sortable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to make an ordered list of items click-and-draggable with the Sortable jQuery UI plugin version 1.8.16. However, I keep getting the error that `$("#ol-id ol").sortable is not a function`, with 'ol-id' being the id of the list. My code is as follows:

```
//Sorting stuff
if($("#li-id li").size()>1) {
    $("#ol-id ol").sortable({
        revert:         true,
        axis:           'y',
        containment:    'parent',
        cursor:         'move',
        handle:         'div.link_div',
        smooth:         false,
        opacity:        0.7,
        tolerance:      'pointer',
        start: function(){
            $("#ol-id").removeClass("bottom_dragged");
        },
        update: function(){
            $("#ol-id ol").sortable({disabled : true});
            $("#saving_indicator").html("saving...")
            $("#saving_indicator").show();
                            //do other stuff...
        }
    })
}
```

Oddly, the error shows up in Firebug as being on the line with `update: function(){`.

I have verified that this function is called after both the page is loaded and the jQuery UI library is loaded. I am including both jquery-1.6.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js in the header. Moreover, I have verified that all id names are correct and match their HTML counterparts.

So if it's not this missing resource-related stuff, what is causing the problem?

EDIT: here is my HTML header:

```
<link href="/_css/styles.css?mod=1317745564" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/_javascript/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css?mod=1315947301" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js">
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/_javascript/sets.js?mod=1320080042" type="text/javascript"> //Sorting stuff code is here
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.selfcheck.vudat.msu.edu/_javascript/jquery.jsonp.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.selfcheck.vudat.msu.edu/_javascript/jquery.form.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.selfcheck.vudat.msu.edu/_javascript/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js">
<link href="/_css/ui/ui.core.css?mod=1315947279" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/_css/ui/ui.theme.css?mod=1315947280" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery UI after jQuery?

Comment: Try `$(this).sortable({disabled : true});` inside `update`, just to check.

Comment: I have verified that jQuery UI is loaded after jQuery and the problem is still here. Also, using 'this' in place of the proper id's does not remove the error. Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: You are including the same libraries like three times. I'd rework that header...

Comment: Yeah, I know it's bloated--that's definitely on my to-do list...

Answer (score 16):

jQuery UI and jQuery must be loaded in a certain order:

```
<script src="jquery.js">...
<script src="jquery-ui.js">...
```

Make sure you are including jQuery UI after jQuery.

Comment: I have verified that JQuery UI is loaded after JQuery. Unfortunately, the problem is still present.

Comment: Can you post your HTML `<head>`?

Comment: @caffeineshots can you post the solution

Comment: @GopinathPerumal in my case it was a silly mistake, i loaded the jquery-ui.js first and that is wrong in order to make jquery-ui work the jquery.js must be loaded first.

Answer (score 11):

So not sure if this will help anyone, but I ran into a similar situation, which I was able to solve. So this seems to happen when either

a) the order of loading jQuery-ui and jQuery is wrong.

b) jQuery is being included more than once, or different versions are being included.

Option "b" happened to me because I was using a bootstrap template, where jQuery is included at the bottom of the document, which is of course a best practice, while the code I was testing added a different version of jQuery at the top of the page.

I see that the code on this question looks like it contains a number of duplicates, so I would suggest cleaning it up as a start.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and it was because another js file was being included at the bottom of the page which had some jQuery functions. When I moved this to the top of the page, above my includes of jQuery and jQuery-UI everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was using **jQuery**(...).sortable() instead of **$**(...).sortable()

Not sure why that mattered, but changing it to **$** fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

i have found new solution,
just edit acf.php file at line number 551

old

```
 'deps'      => array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-datepicker', 'underscore', 'select2'),
```

new

```
 'deps'      => array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-datepicker', 'jquery-ui-sortable', 'underscore', 'select2'),
```

i just added `jquery-ui-sortable` in array
i hope help someone
thank you.