# jQuery .sortable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Even though I've followed the directions in the jQuery UI documentation, I'm getting the error that .sortable is not a function.
Here is my code:

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <span class="caption" style="width: 255px; display: block;">
        Assigned Limits
    </span>
    <div class="assigned-limit-box">
        <ul id="limAssigned" class="ul-base">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my js:

```
$('#limAssigned').sortable();
```

My jQuery js is loaded before my jQuery UI js.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure the jquery UI *build* you are using contains Sortable.

Comment: Thanks.  I have ensured that it does contain Sortable.  It works correctly for another developer I'm working with.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: are you doing this on DOM ready?

Comment: the only error in the console is $(...).sortable is not a function.  this is indeed in my document ready function.

Comment: Can you link to the page or create a jsFiddle example?

Comment: Do you use the whole jQuery UI library or just some widgets/a customized library which you can build on the [jQuery UI Download Builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/) ?

Comment: Works fine for me here http://jsbin.com/itotix/1/edit

Comment: I had a similar issue, because I was loading a second copy of jQuery after loading jQuery UI.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I figured it out. The page that I needed sortable for is loaded into a div within my main page. I had to add the jQuery UI script to that jsp rather than the main page jsp. Funny how that worked out.

Answer (score 40):

I had the same issue when a page using the sortable() function was required by a main php page. Adding the following code within the head of the main page wasn't sufficient. Adding it also at the beginning of the required page (inside the body in my case) fixed everything.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: After a long time, I found this answer and it got my issue resolved  !!!

Comment: You can also use "defer" if you want to call it i n the header

Answer (score 11):

I got this error by having more than 1 version of jQuery on the page. Credit goes to IonicBurger: [jQuery sortable is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956420/jquery-sortable-is-not-a-function/31772031)

Answer (score 2):

it worked for me with this specific version of Jquery

```html
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

but it doesn't work for newer versions

Answer (score 2):

Exactly like **user3279807** in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21604959/11630806, I've found the same issue when i load jQuery from main php page on a one page webapp with dynamic js call.

To fix it you can load jQuery to each page you need or, in my case, in the body. But if you want to keep everything clean in the header, you can also call the JQuery script in the head using `defer`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" defer></script>
```

`defer` is close to `async`. when you call it, the execution of your script start after the load of the the DOM content but before DOMContentLoaded event. When you call multiple scripts with `defer`, the execution of yours scripts keep the order they occur in the page.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI and jQuery must be loaded in a certain order:

```
<script src="jquery.js">...
<script src="jquery-ui.js">...
```

Make sure you are including jQuery UI after jQuery.

Comment: that was actually noted in the original problem, that they were loaded in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

Use both script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this using both the scripts.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```