# Drupal 7 DrupalExp Layer Slider dont let me add a slide

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a drupal site with DrupalExp Layer Slider but when i want to add a new slide does not work.

and only show me this error on console, any idea?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide which slider are you using, how are you integrating the slider module(did you met all the dependency)

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki I use the DrupalExp Layer Slider module. the site comes to me with the module installed, i dont know all dependency. but i read many post on official page like `https://support.drupalexp.com/forum/layer-slider-not-working`, but in their posts, dont show the solution. i think the issue comes with jquery code.

Comment: one thing you need to check, if you are using Jquery ui javascript in your html. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694056/jquery-sortable-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this script to your theme page tpl or via drupal add js or via any preprocess page hook in template.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the latest version of this module here

https://www.drupalexp.com/modules/dexp-layerslider