# JQuery, $(...).sortable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the `.sortable` function in jQuery to sort items in two lists which are in two separate divs (`#groupDiv` and `#userDiv`).

The code below is a function that I snitched from another StackOverflow post just to use as a starting point!

The problem is that the JQuery script is not loading with the page, and I get the error exception "$(...).sortable is not a function" when I load the page.

I have tried downloading various versions of the `jquery-ui.js` file and imported them locally.

I've tried using script links as shown below (instead of storing them locally).

I've tried re-arranging where (and in which order) the scripts are called upon.

I have also checked out the possible solutions found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694056/jquery-sortable-is-not-a-function) post, without success.

**Inserted snippet of how it should work (And it works in the snuippet but not when I run the code thrugh VS)**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".userList, .usersOfGroupList").sortable({
    connectWith: ".dragable",
    remove: function (e, ui) {
     var $this = $(this);
     var childs = $this.find('div');
     if (childs.length === 0) {
      $this.text("Nothing");
     }
    },
    receive: function (e, ui) {
     $(this).contents().filter(function () {
      return this.nodeType == 3;
     }).remove();
    },
   }).disableSelection();
  });
```

```css
#userDiv {
        height: 100%;
        width: 250px;
        margin-left: 1%;
        float: left;
    }

    #groupDiv {
        width: 250px;
        height: 300px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20%;
    }

    #DropDownGroups {
        margin: 1.5% 0 1.5% 0;
        display: block;
        width: 60%;
    }

    #DropDown {
        margin: 1.5% 0 1.5% 0;
        width: 60%;
    }

    #btnGetGroups, #btnShowGroups {
        width: 60%;
        display: block;
    }

    .userList, .usersOfGroupList {
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
        width: 250px;
    }

    .userList {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    .usersOfGroupList {
        margin-top: 1.5%;
    }

    .addBorder {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    #userElement {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 1%;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        width: 100%;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .userContainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 800px; 
    }
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="userContainer">
      <div id="userDiv">
       <ul class="userList dragable">
        <li id='userElement'>Item1</li>
        <li id='userElement'>Item2</li>
        <li id='userElement'>Item3</li>
        <li id='userElement'>Item4</li>
       </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="groupDiv">
       <ul class="usersOfGroupList dragable">
        <li id='userElement'>ItemA</li>
        <li id='userElement'>ItemB</li>
        <li id='userElement'>ItemC</li>
        <li id='userElement'>ItemD</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Based on your code it should work: have you check your browser's dev tools network tab that both `.js` files are successfully loaded?

Comment: What do you get if you enter `$.ui.version` in the console?

Comment: Where have you put your script tags?

Comment: Your code looks ok. In the worst case you can try the source code of the docs itselt bit I think that's not the case: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/. Have you loaded everything in the correct order? Can you verify that both jquery and jquery UI are loaded? Check your dev tools.

Comment: @Terry both files are loaded with statuscode 200!

Comment: @James  I have tried puting them both in the head, body and outside any enclosures, same result!

Comment: @StLia I've checked that the files are loaded in the correct order, all files are loaded but it won't find the function!

Comment: Then I would suggest to follow @j08691 idea and provide us a snippet and we will fix this

Comment: @j08691 I have now included a snippet of the code working, the fault seems to be that the ".sortable" function is'nt being read from the  jquery-ui file, but the browser is looking for it in the jquery file.

Comment: @StLia I have now included a snippet of the code working, the fault seems to be that the ".sortable" function is'nt being read from the jquery-ui file, but the browser is looking for it in the jquery file.

Comment: @PhilipKarlsson Next step would be to check in the console if both libs are loaded $.fn.jquery and $.ui.version. The request succeeds but what about the binding to $ ? That should give us a hint. I am not familiar with VS but I would give it a try with another server. Scotchbox might be the fastest way. I mean the snippet kind of answers the question. There is nothing wrong with the code. I guess it's the server then. I would give a try also to the source code of the official docs: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

So, I think i've found a workaround! Since it is an mvc project I have the BundleConfig.cs in my App_Start folder. after removing this code it now works!:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Note though that I now get this error message : "http://localhost:56043/bundles/jquery 404 (Not Found)". As I said, everything works but will this cause problems in other places?